# Crystal reports - How to put an "OR" condition between 2 fields when joining tables?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, join, crystal-reports

Using Crytal Reports for VS2010, I am writing a new report.
I am trying to figuring out how I can do the following on the report. Please see my SQL that I want to use. Note the first condition in the JOIN which I need assistance with.

```
SELECT * -- <SOME FIELDS HERE>
FROM CUST_ORDER CUST_ORDER
    INNER JOIN "SALES_TX_HDR" "SALES_TX_HDR" ON         
                (CUST_ORDER."cust_order_no"="SALES_TX_HDR".sale_tx_no OR  -- NOTE THIS  CONDITION
                        CUST_ORDER."cust_order_no"="SALES_TX_HDR".status_hdr_no)
            AND CUST_ORDER."branch_no"="SALES_TX_HDR"."status_branch_no"
            AND CUST_ORDER."workstation_no"="SALES_TX_HDR"."status_wrkst_no"
```

I can link the tables but it adds "AND" condition between them, instead of OR.

UPDATE

Let me explain the scenario:

When a new order is placed,

> sale_tx_hdr.sale_tx_no = customerordernumber and
>   sale_tx_hdr.status_hdr_no

is left empty.

When same order is amended, (some more payment made towards the order)

> new sale_tx_hdr.sale_tx_no is created but sale_tx_hdr.status_hdr_no =
>   original order no.

So when I use the OR condition, I get to see both the sale_tx_hdr entries, using any one condition will show me either the amend or new sale or none (if using both conditions with AND)

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any wrong with the `and` condition how does it effects the query behaviour?

Comment: Use a command instead of database expert

Comment: @Siva `AND` and `OR` are completely different boolean operators... Swapping one for another will functionally change the behavior of the inner join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this without using Sql Command.  I havent used command before.

Using an alias of the same table and then joining it on the 2nd field (OR condition) does the trick.

There's a bit of care to be taken when writing the formula though. @Ryan

Comment: Careful with this, you may end up with duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

As Lan already said, you cannot do this in the Database Expert and will need to add the SQL via a SQL Command manually as the data source for your report. You already have the query you want to use, so it should be easy:

When you're creating the report, instead of selecting different tables to add just select the top-most option under your connection called "Add Command" which will allow you to just paste that query in and be used instead. You won't have to worry about visually linking fields, etc. and you'll be able to do all the types of joins that your database supports but Crystal doesn't.